# Photoshop algorithm fixed width and height

Tags: algorithm, crop, photoshop, image-resizing

when a image has the width 2560px  height 1440px, if I want to get the new height when I resize `the width to 1024`, I  get this way

newHeight = dWidth * sourceHeight / sourceWidth;

newHeight now is 576px

I want to know what is the algorithm to get the fixed width and height like does photoshop no matter the width or height, for example the image above width 2560px  height 1440px

if in photoshop I set the crop to width 1024px  height 700px  (fixed width and height)

See the capture:
[image]

Another: crop to width 1024px  height 500px
[image]

Always the image is crop in proportional way to get the fixed width and height.

What is the technique name of this algorithm?

Comment: I don't know if it has a name.  In your first example you are keeping the same aspect ratio as the original image, in the second you are changing it.

Answer (score 0):

In the first example, you are trying to compute the output size.  The formula you show is the best way to do that if you want to retain the aspect ratio.

In the other examples, you're specifying the exact output size and want to compute an input crop that retains that new aspect ratio.  You just rearrange the formula to account for the different knowns and unknown.

```
cropHeight = dWidth * dHeight / sourceWidth;
```

or

```
cropWidth = dHeight * dWidth / sourceHeight;
```